# Query to fetch more than 6500 records in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have requirement in the project to select more than 6500 records from table. 
I have used `select * from tablename where id in (:list)`.
But I am getting `stack overflow` error.

However if the id list is less than 6500 records the query is formed without any errors.

Also the hibernate version is `3.3.ga`, the requirement is I should not upgrade the hibernate version.
Using the current version i should write a query.

Can anybody please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To suggest the obvious: Could you break up the query into several smaller queries?  I also suspect there are other problems with your Java and HQL, but you haven't given us very much to work with.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `setMaxResult()` sinice `LIMIT` is not supported by `hql`

```
String hql = "select * from tablename where id in (:list)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setMaxResults(6500);
List results = query.list();
```